# GroupBy query by Linq.Expressions and Lambdas

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

What I need is to represent this query via Linq.Expressions:

```
db.Documents.GroupBy(a => 1).Select(b => b.Sum(c => c.Amount) });
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
IQueryable<Document> data = db.Documents;

ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Document), "doc");

Expression groupBy = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "GroupBy",
    new Type[] { typeof(Document), typeof(int) },
    data.Expression,
    Expression.Lambda(Expression.Constant(1), pe));

ParameterExpression peg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IGrouping<int, Document>), "group");

Expression select = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "Select",
    new Type[] { typeof(IGrouping<int, Document>), typeof(int) },
    groupBy,
    Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(peg, "Key"), peg));

foreach (var item in data.Provider.CreateQuery(select)) { ... }
```

This was implementation of:

```
db.Documents.GroupBy(a => 1).Select(b => b.Key });
```

And it works perfectly. Now, I want to aggregate a sum instead of accessing the key of group.

That is where it gets tricky for me. I was thinking something like this:

```
ParameterExpression pe1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Document), "other");

Expression sum = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "Sum",
    new Type[] { typeof(Document) },
    peg,
    Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(pe1, "Amount"), pe1));
```

Also, for Sum function in

```
...b.Sum(c => c.Amount)
```

Intellisense gives signature:

```
IEnumerable<Document>.Sum<Document>(Func<Document, decimal> selector)
```

While for:

```
db.Documents.Sum(a => a.Amount)
```

I get:

```
IQueryable<Document>.Sum<Document>(Expression<Func<Document, decimal>> selector)
```

Selector is Func in one version and Expression in other. I don't know how to handle Func in Linq Expressions. Maybe Intellisense is wrong?

Expression for source of aggregation is my biggest issue. By looking at:

```
...b.Sum(c => c.Amount)
```

i would presume that b should be IGrouping (ParameterExpression of 'select'), and that should be the source for Sum, but that won't compile. 
I don't know what else to try?

Here is how last select expression should look like:

```
Expression Select = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "Select",
    new Type[] { typeof(IGrouping<int, Document>), typeof(decimal?) },
    GroupBy,
    Expression.Lambda(sum, peg));
```

But I can't even reach this point, because of the failed 'sum' expression.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Just curious what's the point of grouping by a constant?

Comment: i need several aggregations upon same data at the same time, so it's the only way with single db hit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Intellisense is ok. Let see:

```
db.Documents.GroupBy(a => 1).Select(b => b.Sum(c => c.Amount) });
```

(1) `db.Documents` type is `IQueryable<Document>`
(2) `a` type is `Document`
(3) `db.Documents.GroupBy(a => 1)` type is `IQueryable<IGrouping<int, Document>>`
(4) `b` type is `IGrouping<int, Document>`, [which in turn is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977(v=vs.110).aspx) `IEnumerable<Document>`
(5) `c` type is `Document`

which also means that `GroupBy` and `Select` methods are from `Queryable` while `Sum` is from `Enumerable`.

What about how to distinguish between `Func<...>` and `Expression<Func<...>>` inside the `MethodCall` expressions, the rule is simple. In both cases you use `Expression.Lambda<Func<...>>` to create `Expression<Func<...>>`, and then if the call requires `Func<...>` you pass it directly, and if the method expects `Expression<Func<...>>` then you wrap it with [`Expression.Quote`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.quote(v=vs.110).aspx).

With that being said, let build the sample query expression:

```
var query = db.Documents.AsQueryable();
// query.GroupBy(a => 1)
var a = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Document), "a");
var groupKeySelector = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Constant(1), a);
var groupByCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "GroupBy",
    new Type[] { a.Type, groupKeySelector.Body.Type },
    query.Expression, Expression.Quote(groupKeySelector));
// c => c.Amount
var c = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Document), "c");
var sumSelector = Expression.Lambda(Expression.PropertyOrField(c, "Amount"), c);
// b => b.Sum(c => c.Amount)
var b = Expression.Parameter(groupByCall.Type.GetGenericArguments().Single(), "b");
var sumCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Sum",
    new Type[] { c.Type },
    b, sumSelector);
// query.GroupBy(a => 1).Select(b => b.Sum(c => c.Amount))
var selector = Expression.Lambda(sumCall, b);
var selectCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Select",
    new Type[] { b.Type, selector.Body.Type },
    groupByCall, Expression.Quote(selector));
// selectCall is our expression, let test it
var result = query.Provider.CreateQuery(selectCall);
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan for detailed answer, haven't realized Sum is defined both in Enumerable and Queryable, it was right in front of my eyes.